# C++ Snippets Library

Tags: c++, code-snippets

You know those annoying things that C++ doesn't do very intuitively, like splitting strings on custom delimiters or creating dynamically expanding arrays/vectors... is there any snippet library (I keep seeing boost all over the place, please let me know if that is the solution), that I should be aware of? Or maybe a website that has a number of them so that I can refresh my knowledge of C++... anything to that end is acceptable.

Thanks SOCommunity!

Comment: I would indeed say that Boost has a solution for at least 90% of those inconveniences. Many of them have also been rectified with the new standard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two particular examples you give are both covered by the standard library - `stringstream` and `getline()` to split strings, and `vector` for a dynamic array.

That should be the first place to look; [Boost](http://boost.org) is a good resource when the standard library doesn't meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

For dynamically expanding vectors, you should be using the STL.